# Change the Caret position in Bootstrap Combobox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, combobox, caret

How to change the caret position in multiple bootstrap combobox on click? i just want to make the caret upward when the combobox list is active.

from this site:
https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure thing... add this CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu[style*="block"] + .input-group-addon.dropdown-toggle > .caret{
   border-bottom: 4px solid !important;
   border-top: none  !important;
}
```

That makes it point upward when the list is active.

Comment: 1 more last question please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29556943/accept-value-that-is-not-in-the-list-bootstrap-combobox